# Can access single object from Aws s3 bucket but denied listing objects (SDK for PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, listobject

I have access to this bucket as I'm able to pull single files from it as such:

```
  public function show_s3_object($file_key) {
        $s3_bucket = getenv('S3_BUCKET');
        $s3_key = getenv('S3_KEY');
        $s3_secret = getenv('S3_SECRET');

        if(!empty($file_key))
        {
            $credentials = new Credentials($s3_key, $s3_secret);
            $bucket = $s3_bucket;
            $s3Client = new S3Client([
                'version'     => 'latest',
                'region'      => 'us-east-1', 
                'credentials' => $credentials
            ]);

            $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key'    => $file_key
            ]);

            $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+10 minutes');

            $signedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

            return $signedUrl;
        }
        
    }
```

However when I list objects I get a 403 forbidden. Now there's multiple ways to do this apparently.  I tried most of them like

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('ListObjects', [
                'Bucket' => $bucket
            ]);
```

or

```
$cmd = $s3client->listObjects([
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);
```

Currently on this but still 403 error:

```
 public function list_objects() {
      //correct code semmingly but getting 403 forbidden

        $s3_bucket = getenv('S3_BUCKET');
        $s3_key = getenv('S3_KEY');
        $s3_secret = getenv('S3_SECRET');
        $credentials = new Credentials($s3_key, $s3_secret);
        $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'version'     => 'latest',
            'region'      => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ]);
        try {
            $objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
                'Bucket' => $s3_bucket
            ));
          
           echo "Keys retrieved!\n";
           foreach ($objects as $object) {
               echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
           }
          } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
           }
    
    }
```

Why would I be able to access single objects but not a list of them?

Comment: Please share what policy the bucket has and also can you confirm if you can see all the object list for that bucket in AWS s3 console?

Comment: Yea I think it's a permission issue/bucket policy at this point.  My infrastructure team is working on it now.  I thought because I could access single objects the permissions and the bucket policy would not deny listing objects as well.  Also our operations team is the only one with AWS dashboard access, they hand out the keys to us but that's it.  So kind of stuck, wish I could supply you that stuff.  But thanks